# Scalar curvature in ADM Formalism (coordinate to coordinate-free transition)

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, differentiation, adm-formalism

I am attempting to express the scalar curvature in a coordinate-independent manner. Following the works of [Bojowald](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/canonical-gravity-and-applications/88843142AC5617F84ED0E1FE2742E9C3), [Thiemann](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/modern-canonical-quantum-general-relativity/7EB982BB5AD3DA54CCE265732685CDAF), we have:
$$ {}^{(4)}R= {}^{(3)}R+K_{a b}K^{a b}- (K_a^a)^2 - 2\nabla_a v^a, \qquad v^a=-n^a\nabla_c n^c+n^c\nabla_c n^a$$
According to my [Wöhr](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/56769298.pdf), we must get
$$ {}^{(4)}R= {}^{(3)}R+tr(K^2)-(tr K)^2+2div(\nabla_n n+div(n)n)$$

The only non-trivial term is the divergence term, while the others are straightforward.

We must prove that
$$- \nabla_a v^a= div(\nabla_n n+div(n)n)$$

What I've attempt so far is
\begin{align}
\nabla_a v^a&=-\nabla_a( n^a\nabla_c n^c-n^c\nabla_c n^a)
\newline &=-(\nabla_a n^a)(\nabla_c n^c)-n^a \nabla_a \nabla_c n^c +\nabla_a \nabla_n n^a
\newline &= -(div\ n)^2-n(div\ n)+\nabla_a \nabla_n n^a
\end{align}
Using that $div(div(n)n)=n(div\;n)+div(n)^2$ (was proved in Wöhr, p.185), we get
$$-\nabla_a v^a=div(div(n)n)-\nabla_a \nabla_n n^a$$

Here's the problem: if $\nabla_a \nabla_n n^a=\nabla_a (\nabla_n n)^a$,  $\nabla_a \nabla_n n^a=div(\nabla_n n)$ and we are done. But I don't see why that could be true.

How can one deal with this? Its just some minor notation abuse or its a real problem in this calculation ?